# angular mat date picker range hover going to next week when hovered over Sunday

Tags: angular, typescript, date, angular-material

i am using angular material datepicker but when i hover over Sunday it selects the next week [my datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwv16.png). i think this is because i changed the first day to Monday using

```
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    override getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

my typescript i use to get the range of the week:

```
@Injectable()
export class FiveDayRangeSelectionStrategy<D> implements MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy<D> {
  constructor(private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>) {}

  selectionFinished(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    return this._createFiveDayRange(date);
  }

  createPreview(activeDate: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    return this._createFiveDayRange(activeDate);
  }

  private _createFiveDayRange(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    if (date) {
      console.log(date)
      const start = this._getMondayBefore(date);
      const end = this._getSundayAfter(start);
      return new DateRange<D>(start, end);
    }
    return new DateRange<D>(null, null);
  }
  private _getMondayBefore(date: D): D {
    const dayOfWeek = this._dateAdapter.getDayOfWeek(date);
    const daysToSubtract = dayOfWeek - (this._dateAdapter.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    return this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, -daysToSubtract);
  }

  private _getSundayAfter(date: D): D {
    const dayOfWeek = this._dateAdapter.getDayOfWeek(date);
    const daysToAdd = 8 - dayOfWeek - this._dateAdapter.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    return this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, daysToAdd);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-browser',
  templateUrl: './browser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./browser.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
      useClass: FiveDayRangeSelectionStrategy,
    },
  ],
})
```

and my html:

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
        <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
          <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
          <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
        </mat-date-range-input>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

i tried changing the `daysToAdd` and `daysToSubtract` but this just changes the range. and not the fact that it selects the next week when hovered over Sunday. anyone knows how to get it so it selects the current Monday to Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would create a `_createCurrentWeekRange()` function:

```
private _createCurrentWeekRange(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
  if (date) {
    const dow = this._dateAdapter.getDayOfWeek(date);
    const start = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, -(dow + 6) % 7);
    const end = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(start, 6);
    return new DateRange<D>(start, end);
  }
  return new DateRange<D>(null, null);
}
```

I derived the number of days difference between the current day, and the Monday in the same week from the following table:

| Day of week | Days difference with Monday (1) |
| --- | --- |
| Sunday (0) | -6 days |
| Monday (1) | 0 days |
| Tuesday (2) | -1 days |
| Wednesday (3) | -2 days |
| Thursday (4) | -3 days |
| Friday (5) | -4 days |
| Saturday (6) | -5 days |

This gives us a formula of `daysDifference = -(dayOfWeek + 6) % 7`. To calculate the Sunday of the same week, it then just becomes a matter of adding 6 days to the date of the Monday.

If you want to make things more generic, and want to take situations into account where the first day of the week can be another day than Monday, the formula becomes `daysDifference = -(dayOfWeek + 7 - firstDayOfWeek) % 7`, as demonstrated in this table:

[image: Days difference]

The implementation then becomes something like:

```
private _createCurrentWeekRange(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
  if (date) {
    const dow = this._dateAdapter.getDayOfWeek(date);
    const first = this._dateAdapter.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    const start = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, -(dow + 7 - first) % 7);
    const end = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(start, 6);
    return new DateRange<D>(start, end);
  }
  return new DateRange<D>(null, null);
}
```

Comment: when i use this code, the same happens but on Monday and it selects the previous week. and how would u simplify it. i wanna learn the 'best' way to code

Comment: @JochemBergers I rewrote my answer.